# GAMS Display style

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gams-math

How do I  display a text in GAMS?
For example: in MATLAB I can use disp('MATLAB'), then I will get the output as MATLAB.

Is it possible to have like this in GAMS. In fact, I am new with GAMS environment.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

display "Hi, warning message here!"

... should work. This will appear in your .LST file, which you should get familiar with reading for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two ways:

- `$log "text to display"` if you want it to appear during the **compilation phase** (and shows only in .log file)
- `display "text to display" ;` if you want it to appear during the **execution phase** (and shows only in .lst file)